# MongoDB Shell aggregate pipeline not grouping how I want it to

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

**Design and implement a MongoDB aggregation pipeline to show the total number of employees by state for all companies that have offices in the United States.**

My original solution is this:

```
db.research.aggregate([
   { $match: { "offices.country_code": "USA" } },
   { $group: { _id: "$offices.state_code", total: { $sum: "$number_of_employees" } } }
])
```

The problem is that each document can have multiple `offices`, resulting in many of the returned results being combinations of different state codes. For example, these are some results:

```
{ "_id" : [ null, "IL" ], "total" : 61 }
{ "_id" : [ "NY", "CA", null ], "total" : 20 }
{ "_id" : [ "UT", "CA", "NY", null ], "total" : 0 }
{ "_id" : [ null, "GA", null, null ], "total" : 0 }
{ "_id" : [ "WA", "WA", "NY", "CA", "MA", null ], "total" : 1650 }
{ "_id" : [ "TX", "IL" ], "total" : 22 }
{ "_id" : [ "MA", "NV" ], "total" : 0 }
{ "_id" : [ "NY", "CO", "CA" ], "total" : 0 }
{ "_id" : [ "MA", "MA" ], "total" : 25 }
{ "_id" : [ "VA", "NY", "CA", null, null ], "total" : 5 }
{ "_id" : [ "CA", "CA", "NY", "IL", "CA", null, null ], "total" : 0 }
{ "_id" : [ "CA", null, "NY", "CA", null ], "total" : 50 }
{ "_id" : [ "CA", "ME" ], "total" : 2 }
{ "_id" : [ "MA" ], "total" : 255864 }
{ "_id" : [ "DE" ], "total" : 409 }
{ "_id" : [ "DC", "CA", "VA" ], "total" : 7000 }
{ "_id" : [ "ND" ], "total" : 18 }
{ "_id" : [ null, null, "VA", null, null, null, "VT", null, null ], "total" : 0 }
{ "_id" : [ "NC", null, null, null ], "total" : 290 }
{ "_id" : [ "SC", "NY" ], "total" : 0 }
```

Instead, I want each ``state_code` listed separately with the number of employees for that state. If a document has multiple state codes, it should count towards each of them. For example, If a document has 1000 employees and the state codes "NY" and "CA", the 1000 should count towards both of those sums. I don't want it to list unique combinations of state codes like it currently is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deconstruct `offices` array before group,

- `$unwind` to deconstruct `offices` array

```
db.research.aggregate([
  { $match: { "offices.country_code": "USA" } },
  { $unwind: "$offices" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$offices.state_code",
      total: { $sum: "$number_of_employees" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A15copn4aJU)